# Not able to log into phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

`UserID = Root` with `password = blank` doesn't work to get me logged into `phpMyAdmin` on localhost. Also uncommented `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;` on `config.ini` and still can't log into `phpMyAdmin`. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter AllowNoPassword = TRUE directive in config file with also root user:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
```